# setOnDayClickListener is not executing for calendar application how can i solve this problem?

Tags: android

setOnDayClickListener is not working  for calendar app

```
   calendarView=(CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendarView);


    calendarView.setOnDayClickListener(new OnDayClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDayClick(EventDay eventDay) {
            Calendar clickedDayCalendar = eventDay.getCalendar();
        }
    });
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve add more details

Comment: I want to develop a calendar application  using material android view

Answer (score 0):

```
CalendarView calendarView = findViewById(R.id.calendarView);

    calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarView, int year, int month, int date) {


        }
    });
```

Try this code. This will give you the year, month and date

Comment: This code is not working, it does not showing error but no output .

Comment: Try to print year, month and date in day change listener

Answer (score 0):

Hope you find this useful.This code will open the material callendar. You can even adjust the data time range using setmaxdate and setmindate else ignore it

```
       final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            final Calendar calendarMin = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendarMin.set(yy, mm - 1, dd);
            DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(ItemsOnDemandFilterActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    String date = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + "-" + String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1)
                            + "-" + String.valueOf(year);
                    startDateEditText.setText(date);
                }
            }, yy, mm, dd);
            datePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
            datePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendarMin.getTimeInMillis());
            datePicker.show();
```